Freezing occurs when playing videos continuously using Vlc.DotNet
Freezing occurs when playing videos continuously using Vlc.DotNet?
The program code is as follows:
int ListNum = 0;
List<string> PlayList = new List<string>();
string[] AllFiles;

private void PlayVedioFiles() {
    vlcControl1.Audio.Volume = 0;
    ListNum = 0;
    AllFiles = Directory.GetFiles("F:\\VedioFiles");
    foreach (string strFile in AllFiles) {
        PlayList.Add(strFile);
    }
    SetThreadPool();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => this.vlcControl1.Play(new System.IO.FileInfo(PlayList[ListNum])));
}

private void vlcControl1_EndReached(object sender, Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayerEndReachedEventArgs e) {
    if (ListNum >= PlayList.Count) {
        ListNum = 0;
    }
    if (ListNum < PlayList.Count) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => this.vlcControl1.Play(new System.IO.FileInfo(PlayList[ListNum++])));
    }
}

How to deal with it?

Already asked, but trying again: why do you have ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() there? Did you find any suggestion in the VLC sample code repo that suggests this is a good idea? Spoiler alert: it's not

@Jimi : actually there is a reason and an official recommendation to do so : https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet/wiki/Vlc.DotNet-freezes-(don't-call-Vlc.DotNet-from-a-Vlc.DotNet-callback)

@Zonghan zhan : Vlc DotNet has not been maintained for years. That being said, what libvlc version are you using? I think a remember a bug in a 3.x version of libvlc that has been reported in vlc's tracker. Try to update the libvlc version and see if things get better. Anyway, that sounds like a libvlc issue

@cube45 No, it's not that recommendation. That's why I asked. You can try to enqueue a MediaPlayer (IMO, still not the way to solve the underlying issue, that you generate by blocking a callback of an external library. No idea why you would do that), not when working with an instance of a WinForms's Control, trying to do anything with it in a non-STAThread environment, or, in any case, in a Thread other than the Thread that created it. I have to say I'm not familiar with Vlc.DoNet, more with LibVLCSharp and its VideoView object, but that's not something I would recommend doing anyway

@cube45 The OP, if it's really necessary issuing another command from the callback itself, could try to BeginInvoke() the command (i.e., BeginInvoke(() => vlcControl1.Play(...), or using new Action(() => (...)), depending on the .NET version in use, which is also undefined here), so the callback is released, and the new action is enqueued in the main Thread's message loop
